# git on Ubuntu get: gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized

Tags: git, ssl

When I run: 'git clone ...' from **Linux**, I successfully clone it.

but when I run the same command form **Ubuntu** I get the following error message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitserver...': gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized
```

I also run :

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1  git clone  https://gitserver...
```

On the **Ubuntu** machine I get the output:

```
Cloning into 'aaa'...
* Couldn't find host gitserver in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Adding handle: conn: 0x24af4a0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x24af4a0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to gitserver port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 111.222.333.444...
* Connected to gitserver (111.222.333.444) port 443 (#0)
* error reading ca cert file /etc/httpd/cert/bbb.crt (Error while reading file.)
* gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized
*        common name: WARNING couldn't obtain
*        server certificate verification SKIPPED
```

On **Linux** I get:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /path/to/aaa/.git/
* Couldn't find host gitserver in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to gitserver port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 111.222.333.444... * Connected to gitserver (111.222.333.444) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate:
 .......
```

and here I get the data okay.

What the different between Ubuntu and Redhat?

Thanks.

Comment: When I write Linux, I meant Redhat

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED for me**

I found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766961/git-trouble-via-https-routinesssl23-get-server-hello the sollotion that work for me:

I add the line

```
BrowserMatch "git" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

to the configuration file of apache.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to deal with this issue myself at a new job.  I'm using 14.04 LTS and my problem was apparently that the server name I was using to address the git repo was actually an alias in the DNS server for another server name.  When I used the other server name, I had no problems, and I did not need to install a cert or change anything on the server side.